# Android Resources vs R

Tags: android

In android I can do the following (both return ints):

```
R.color.my_color;
```

vs

```
Resources myR = getResources();
myR.getColor(R.color.my_color);
```

What is the difference as they both return ints?

Answer (score 2):

`R.color.my_color` only contains the ID of your resource, so it's just an identifier.

`getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color);` contains the actual color. Here, you use color ID to load actual color.

Where are you going to use this color?

Comment: Thanks, got it. I guess I as expecting a Color object instead of an int reference to a color

Comment: Well, a color is just a 'group' of numbers for alpha, red, green and blue (#aarrggbb) so it's expressed as an int. If you see object Color, it just contains int constants and methods (most are static).

Answer (score 1):

`R.color.my_color` will return the id of the resource, not the color itself.